# Dajngo: Pagination in search results with Class-based views

Tags: python, django, pagination

I want to paginate by keywords that I enter in the form.

I use the following class

```
def pageNotFound(request, exceprion):
    return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>Page not found</h2>")


def get_quotes():

    top_tags = get_top_tags()

    context = {
        "top_tags": top_tags,
        "functional_menu": functional_menu,
    }

    return context


class Main(ListView):
    model = Quote
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "quotes/index.html"
    context_object_name = "quotes"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(get_quotes())
        return context

class SearchedResults(ListView):
    model = Quote
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "quotes/index.html"
    context_object_name = "quotes"

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("search_query")
        if query:
            queryset = Quote.objects.filter(
                Q(quote__icontains=query)
                | Q(tags__name__icontains=query)
                | Q(author__fullname__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        else:
            queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

The problem is that when you go to the next page, the form field is cleared and the query takes the value None `query=None`. The entire pagination becomes undefined. How to save queryset when crossing pages in pagination?

Comment: Can't you just add `search_query` as query parameter in the links to the next pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not much to do with the view, but the links of the pagination. You can create a helper function in the view:

```
class SearchedResults(ListView):
    model = Quote
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'quotes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'quotes'

    def urlencode_search(self):
        qd = self.request.GET.copy()
        qd.pop(self.page_kwarg, None)
        return qd.urlencode()

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search_query')
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(quote__icontains=query)
                | Q(tags__name__icontains=query)
                | Q(author__fullname__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        return queryset
```

In the template, you then link to a different page with:

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&amp;{{ view.urlencode_search }}">next page</a>
```

and this for all links that go to a page.